# ActiveSync File Explorer alternative

Tags: windows-mobile, activesync

Is there an alternative to the ActiveSync "Explore" for looking at the file system of a Windows Mobile device?  (This same thing can also be accessed from My Computer -> Mobile Device).  It would be nice if you could just navigate into the device and view or edit files without having to copy them back and forth from the PC.

Why does it work this way in the first place?  Is the Explore view sort of a "virtual" version of your phone's file system that cannot be edited directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this:  [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/).  Has anyone used it?  It looks like it has a long history (since Windows 3.1), which could be a good or bad thing.

Comment: Yeah I've used it on my PPC, its pretty good, shows all file and file extensions, unlike file explorer on the device.

Answer (score 1):

For me it is in MUST BE INSTALLED software category. Cant imagine work with data without it. Highly recomended.

p.s. In last few years it is getting almost as good free alternative: FreeCommander.